# How to execute JavaScript code when click Button in Webflow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, document-ready, webflow

I am newbie in Webflow, In Webflow project I want to get button by id and execute some Javascript code when I click this button.

The code I write:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
       let btn = document.getElementById('myButtonId');
       btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
           // handle the click event
           console.log('clicked');
           alert("Hello");
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to move the code to the Page Footer,

or wrap the code in the Webflow's recommended "Webflow ready function":

```
var Webflow = Webflow || {};
Webflow.push(function() {

    // Your code goes here
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
       let btn = document.getElementById('myButtonId');
       btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          ...
       });
    });

}); // End Webflow ready function
```

Answer (score -2):

Java script you can call the function any name you want

```
 <script>
            function yourFunctionName() {
            alert("hello")
            };
        
        </script>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <button id="myButtonId" onclick="yourFunctionName ()">click here</button>
 
</body>
```

Comment: I am taking about Webflow project